# Yii Framework - Delete Multiple, sending form results

Tags: php, yii

At the moment I've got a function where I can delete multiple items from my database from a CGridView which is working fine. The only problem is that I want to direct the user to a confirmation page before deleting the items.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Submit the value you need to delete at a first action.
   This action renders the data you want to show and then asks for confirmation or reject. (eg: active field not editable or hidden field that replies the value for submit)
2. Use the confirm button of this view to submit confirmed data to the second action that will make deletions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete rookie at this (obviously) could you just clarify how I do that?

Comment: @AlecGamble onclick "button": redirect to a new page. Pass the ids of the items to delete. ask for confirmation with two buttons. onclick "yes": redirect to delete code with the ids. onclick "no": redirect back or wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind using a javascript confirm box? If yes, in your first view change

```
<a class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Delete Selected'); ?></a>
```

to

```
<a class="btn btn-danger">
  <?php echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Delete Selected', array('confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete?')); ?>
</a>
```

**EDIT: If changing style is not an issue. The above part still works.**

Also, I think you can change a tag and use the bootstrap classes in button.

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::SubmitButton('Delete Selected',
    array(
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete?',
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution isn't practical to me because it has to be in keeping with the style that is already in place, sorry but thank you!

Comment: @AlecGamble you can ignore the last part of the answer if you don't want to change style. The above part will still work. I'll separate the answers.

Comment: it's not that, it's just that the javascript confirm box isn't in keeping with the rest of the site which is to redirect the user to a page which asks them to confirm deleting it.

Comment: Okay, in that case you may want to follow what [scaisEdge answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34296056/2733146)